# Group by various column (with various joins) but sum distinct other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to do some reporting, involving various tables, and having couple of SUMs, COUNTs, etc and everything is OK. But the last thing I have to resolve is SUM by another which is not in the grouped columns. 
I'll give you an example (stripped down from what I have) so you can understand the tongue-twister in the previous paragraph.

Suppose I have a query with a couple of joins that get me this result, or a temporary table, or whatever:
(this is a trimmed down version, in the original I have much more columns and groupbys)

`APP_ID  CAT_ID  CAT_DESCRIP  APP_START  APP_END  DETAIL_ID  DET_QTY  DETAIL_PRICE
     1       1  Categ One         900      960          1       10         150.00
     1       1  Categ One         900      960          2        8          20.00
     1       1  Categ One         900      960          3       12          30.00
     1       1  Categ One         900      960          4        5         100.00
     2       2  Categ Two         600      720          5       12         150.00
     2       2  Categ Two         600      720          6       10          50.00
     3       2  Categ Two        1200     1260          7        5          20.00`

**I need to get something like this: *(the bolded column is the important)***

`SELECT 
    CAT_ID,
    CAT_DESCRIP,
    SUM(DET_QTY) as TotalQTY,
    SUM(DETAIL_PRICE) as TotalPrice,
    COUNT(DISTINCT APP_ID) as CountOfApps,
    (GET THE SUM OF (APP_END - APP_START) ONLY ONE TIME BY APP_ID INTO THIS CATEG) as TimeInMinutesByCategory
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    CAT_ID`

And the result has to give me this:

`CAT_ID  CAT_DESCRIP  TotalQTY  TotalPrice  CountOfApps  TimeInMinutesByCategory
     1  Categ One          35      300.00            1                       60
     2  Categ Two          27      220.00            2                      180`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the job... or if not, a little tweaking on the sytnax for max(app_start) - max(app_end) should do the job

The idea is, summarize the data in a subquery by app_id and cat_id. Select the max value of start and end, grouped by app_id and cat_id. Since there will only be one value per each distinct pair of app_id and cat_id, we're essentially just deduping.

Then, join the subquery to the main query and summarize by category id.

```
SELECT 
    a.CAT_ID,
    a.CAT_DESCRIP,
    SUM(a.DET_QTY) as TotalQTY,
    SUM(a.DETAIL_PRICE) as TotalPrice,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.APP_ID) as CountOfApps,
    SUM(b.TimeInMinutesByCategory) AS TimeInMinutesByCategory
FROM
MyTable AS a
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT APP_ID, CAT_ID, max(app_start) - max(app_end) AS TimeInMinutesByCategory
     FROM MyTable
     GROUP BY APP_ID, CAT_ID) AS b
ON a.cat_id = b.cat_id
AND a.app_id = b.app_id
GROUP BY
    a.CAT_ID
```